# How do I use Intent to go to one of five (user selected via tab) activities?

Tags: android, android-intent, tabs, sharedpreferences, intentfilter

On my main activity I have a tab with 5 choices. I am trying to write in persistence using SharedPreferences to allow the user to select one of the tabs (as well as set a timer), and then those selections are saved so that one of five activities will come up when the "Start" button is pushed. I am trying to write this functionality into an Intent in the onClickListener for the "Start" button, so that it will use the currently selected tab and go to the the activity that goes with that tab. The 5 tabs, all have their own themed activity that they will go to (not by clicking the tab, but rather the "Start" button), so what should my Intent code show in order for this to happen?

I was thinking, the choice of activity should go into the 2nd parameter of the new Intent() part of the code, since that determines which class it goes to (for now I have a "dummy" activity in there, but it should be changed). But since it must be based on what the user selected (whichever tab is currently selected), it should somehow say that, but how? Or is the answer to write an implicit Intent (which, from my limited understanding, allows an Intent to choose from multiple factors in determining the best activity to go to)?

I am not writing in the value to be saved (and passed on) for the timer set up yet, so we just need to focus on the tab selection being saved and passed through an Intent for now. Thanks for your help.

P.S. I'm not quite sure my SharedPreferences code is correct, so suggest changes if you think something is wrong.

NOTE: PLEASE, PLEASE let me know if this question is unclear. This is the 2nd time I've asked it (simplified from the last time) and I'm so far not getting a response. I just really need to know how to go from one tab choice through the Intent to the activity associated with that tab choice (so, one of five choices). How can an Intent allow room for this choice? I MUST use SharedPreferences for other reasons (the timer) but really, this posting is about how to properly write an Intent, so don't get too hung up on the SharedPreferences part. If anyone can attempt an answer, I would be so very, very grateful, thanks you in advance!!

**MainSelectorActivity.java**

```
package com.azurespot.disastertimer.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.azurespot.disastertimer.app.tabs.GodzillaTab;
import com.azurespot.disastertimer.app.tabs.NuclearTab;
import com.azurespot.disastertimer.app.tabs.TsunamiTab;
import com.azurespot.disastertimer.app.tabs.VolcanoTab;
import com.azurespot.disastertimer.app.tabs.ZombieTab;


public class MainSelectorActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    Resources resrc;
    FragmentTabHost tabHost;
    private Button btnStart;
    public static final String TABTIMER = "Tab_and_Timer";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_selector);

        tabSetUp();

        btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MediaActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        tabAndTimerPersist();

    }

    public void tabSetUp() {
        resrc = getResources();

        // TabHost setup & functionality
        tabHost = (android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        //------Zombie tab------
        //Creates tab and sets zombie image in view
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("zombie").setIndicator("",
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_zombie_selected)),
                ZombieTab.class, null);

        //------Nuclear tab------
        //Creates tab and sets nuclear image in view
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("nuclear").setIndicator("",
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_nuclear_selected)),
                NuclearTab.class, null);

        //------Tsunami tab------
        //Creates tab and sets tsunami image in view
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tsunami").setIndicator("",
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_tsunami_selected)),
                TsunamiTab.class, null);

        //------Godzilla tab------
        //Creates tab and sets tsunami image in view
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("godzilla").setIndicator("",
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_godzilla_selected)),
                GodzillaTab.class, null);

        //------Volcano tab------
        //Creates tab and sets volcano image in view
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("volcano").setIndicator("",
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_volcano_selected)),
                VolcanoTab.class, null);

        //set Zombie tab as default (zero based)
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        tabAndTimerPersist();
    }

    private void tabAndTimerPersist() {

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(TABTIMER, MODE_PRIVATE);

        tabHost.getCurrentTab();

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("zombie", 0);
        editor.putInt("nuclear", 0);
        editor.putInt("tsunami", 0);
        editor.putInt("godzilla", 0);
        editor.putInt("volcano", 0);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
TabHost tabHost;
Intent intent;
TabHost.TabSpec spec;
Resources res;
            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("A")
            .setIndicator(getTabView("A","#333333"))
            .setContent(new Intent().setClass(this,A.class));
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    spec = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("B")
            .setIndicator(getTabView("B","#ffffff"))
            .setContent(new Intent().setClass(this,B.class));
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
        setTabColor(tabHost);
```

//Your on tab change listener call setTabColor(tabHost);

```
private View getTabView(String text, String color) 
{
    LayoutInflater inf_manifesto=getLayoutInflater();
    View v=inf_manifesto.inflate(R.layout.customt_tab, null);
        TextView t = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    t.setText(text);
    t.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(color));

    return v;
}
   public static void setTabColor(TabHost tabhost)
{
    for(int i=0;i<tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
    {

 tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3d99d1"));
        TextView tv1 = (TextView)tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.txt);
        tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

    }
    tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabhost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")); // selected
    TextView tv2 = (TextView)tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabhost.getCurrentTab()).findViewById(R.id.txt);
    tv2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));

}
```

Use this way to create tabs.

Comment: hello, and thanks for your efforts. although that looks very different from my code, and doesn't explain what does what, so i am afraid i don't really understand what is going on. is it really difficult for an Intent to choose from multiple activity based on a tab selection? i guess in theory it seemed simple. plus i am unclear why you wrote the layout information in into a .java format, since the layout was fine and not addressed in the question. perhaps you you could explain your reasoning, or the steps of what is going on. thanks.

Comment: oh don't take it hard,its too easy and if you only want to switch tabs then you should use  .setContent(newIntent().setClass(this,A.class)); Let me know in case of more help.